# Tippecanoe vector tiles duplicating over certain graticules (equator, -90)

Tags: vector, mapbox, vector-tiles, duplication, tippecanoe

I have large geojsons at different scales that I have converted to tiles with `tippecanoe`. My ultimate goal is for a user to be able to draw a box around the tiles and calculate mean attribute values for the drawn box.

When I generate the tiles with a very basic tippecanoe call, the visual result of the tiles is exactly like the geojson. However, when I draw a box around the tiles to extract the attribute values, there are duplicate tiles/values. These duplicates occur over the equator and -90 degrees longitude.

Here is a snippet of the data as geojson:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "galapagos",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "value": 0.14843152027673248 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -91.909801610152726, 0.357999991917723 ], [ -91.164601610152729, 0.357999991917723 ], [ -91.164601610152729, -0.360200008082273 ], [ -91.909801610152726, -0.360200008082273 ], [ -91.909801610152726, 0.357999991917723 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "value": 0.22332188561558725 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -91.164601610152729, 0.357999991917723 ], [ -90.419401610152732, 0.357999991917723 ], [ -90.419401610152732, -0.360200008082273 ], [ -91.164601610152729, -0.360200008082273 ], [ -91.164601610152729, 0.357999991917723 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "value": 0.1333752835203928 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -91.909801610152726, -0.360200008082273 ], [ -91.164601610152729, -0.360200008082273 ], [ -91.164601610152729, -1.078400008082284 ], [ -91.909801610152726, -1.078400008082284 ], [ -91.909801610152726, -0.360200008082273 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "value": 0.29434766525938078 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -91.164601610152729, -0.360200008082273 ], [ -90.419401610152732, -0.360200008082273 ], [ -90.419401610152732, -1.078400008082284 ], [ -91.164601610152729, -1.078400008082284 ], [ -91.164601610152729, -0.360200008082273 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "value": 0.35693175588237375 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -90.419401610152732, -0.360200008082273 ], [ -89.674201610152735, -0.360200008082273 ], [ -89.674201610152735, -1.078400008082284 ], [ -90.419401610152732, -1.078400008082284 ], [ -90.419401610152732, -0.360200008082273 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "value": 0.16528774400552115 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -89.674201610152735, -0.360200008082273 ], [ -88.929001610152724, -0.360200008082273 ], [ -88.929001610152724, -1.078400008082284 ], [ -89.674201610152735, -1.078400008082284 ], [ -89.674201610152735, -0.360200008082273 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "value": 0.28086676990130433 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -91.164601610152729, -1.078400008082284 ], [ -90.419401610152732, -1.078400008082284 ], [ -90.419401610152732, -1.796600008082279 ], [ -91.164601610152729, -1.796600008082279 ], [ -91.164601610152729, -1.078400008082284 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "value": 0.35032997032006585 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -90.419401610152732, -1.078400008082284 ], [ -89.674201610152735, -1.078400008082284 ], [ -89.674201610152735, -1.796600008082279 ], [ -90.419401610152732, -1.796600008082279 ], [ -90.419401610152732, -1.078400008082284 ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

With the basic tile generation of `tippecanoe -z2 -Z0 -s EPSG:4326 -f galapagos.geojson galapagos.mbtiles`, I get the following result:

[image: 8 tiles]

Visually, this looks correct. However, 4 of the 8 tiles have duplicate tiles/values. Referencing [Tippecanoe's documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe#controlling-clipping-to-tile-boundaries), I tried adding the `--no-duplication` and `-b 0` flags to solve the duplication problem.

Running `tippecanoe -z2 -Z0 -s EPSG:4326 -f galapagos.geojson galapagos_no_dupe.mbtiles --no-duplication` shows where the polygons are behaving strangely...the green lines are the equator and -90 degrees. In the above example, the 4 split squares that intersect the graticules are the ones with duplicate values.

[image]

Further, setting the buffer to 0 with `tippecanoe -z2 -Z0 -s EPSG:4326 -f galapagos.geojson galapagos_b0.mbtiles -b 0` results in this:

[image]

Is there a way that I can generate tiles to output exactly as the first image with the 8 attribute values and no splitting or duplication?